# Traefik unable to get letsencrypt certificate

Tags: docker

I'm trying to set up traefik with portainer so that I can create apps on `*.vps.ahri.net`, served over https from letsencrypt.

I'm using cloudflare as my DNS and have an `A` record for `vps.ahri.net`, and a `CNAME` of `*.vps` pointing to that `A` record.

I'm using `Docker version 17.12.1-ce, build 7390fc6` and `docker-compose version 1.19.0, build 9e633ef`.

My configuration files are as follows:

traefik/docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.3.5
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - web
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
    container_name: traefik

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

traefik/traefik.toml:

```
debug = true

logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "vps.ahri.net"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false

[acme]
email = "adam@ahri.net"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
OnHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```

And finally, portainer/docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2.1"

services:
  app:
    image: portainer/portainer
    restart: always
    networks:
      - web
      - default
    expose:
      - "9000"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./data:/data
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=my-awesome-app-app"
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:docker.vps.ahri.net"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.port=9000"
      - "traefik.default.protocol=https"

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

As you can see above, I've switched on debugging as the ACME stuff doesn't seem to be working:

```
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:27Z" level=info msg="Traefik version v1.3.5 built on 2017-08-01_04:18:59PM"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:27Z" level=info msg="Using TOML configuration file //traefik.toml"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:27Z" level=debug msg="Global configuration loaded {"GraceTimeOut":10000000000,"Debug":true,"CheckNewVersion":true,"AccessLogsFile":"","TraefikLogsFile":"","LogLevel":"DEBUG","EntryPoints":{"http":{"Network":"","Address":":80","TLS":null,"Redirect":{"EntryPoint":"https","Regex":"","Replacement":""},"Auth":null,"Compress":false},"https":{"Network":"","Address":":443","TLS":{"MinVersion":"","CipherSuites":null,"Certificates":null,"ClientCAFiles":null},"Redirect":null,"Auth":null,"Compress":false}},"Cluster":null,"Constraints":[],"ACME":{"Email":"adam@ahri.net","Domains":null,"Storage":"acme.json","StorageFile":"","OnDemand":false,"OnHostRule":true,"CAServer":"","EntryPoint":"https","DNSProvider":"","DelayDontCheckDNS":0,"ACMELogging":false,"TLSConfig":null},"DefaultEntryPoints":["https","http"],"ProvidersThrottleDuration":2000000000,"MaxIdleConnsPerHost":200,"IdleTimeout":180000000000,"InsecureSkipVerify":false,"Retry":{"Attempts":0},"HealthCheck":{"Interval":30000000000},"Docker":{"Watch":true,"Filename":"","Constraints":null,"Endpoint":"unix:///var/run/docker.sock","Domain":"vps.ahri.net","TLS":null,"ExposedByDefault":false,"UseBindPortIP":false,"SwarmMode":false},"File":null,"Web":null,"Marathon":null,"Consul":null,"ConsulCatalog":null,"Etcd":null,"Zookeeper":null,"Boltdb":null,"Kubernetes":null,"Mesos":null,"Eureka":null,"ECS":null,"Rancher":null,"DynamoDB":null}"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:27Z" level=info msg="Preparing server http &{Network: Address::80 TLS:<nil> Redirect:0xc4203195c0 Auth:<nil> Compress:false}"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:27Z" level=info msg="Preparing server https &{Network: Address::443 TLS:0xc4204fd140 Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> Compress:false}"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:27Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :80"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:27Z" level=info msg="Loading ACME Account..."
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:27Z" level=info msg="Loaded ACME config from store acme.json"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:27Z" level=debug msg="Building ACME client..."
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg=AgreeToTOS...
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *docker.Provider {"Watch":true,"Filename":"","Constraints":null,"Endpoint":"unix:///var/run/docker.sock","Domain":"vps.ahri.net","TLS":null,"ExposedByDefault":false,"UseBindPortIP":false,"SwarmMode":false}"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=info msg="Retrieving ACME certificates..."
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=info msg="Retrieved ACME certificates"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Testing certificate renew..."
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :443"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Provider connection established with docker 17.12.1-ce (API 1.35)"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container /traefik"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Validation of load balancer method for backend backend-my-awesome-app-app-default failed: invalid load-balancing method ''. Using default method wrr."
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider docker: {"backends":{"backend-my-awesome-app-app-default":{"servers":{"service":{"url":"https://172.18.0.3:9000","weight":0}},"loadBalancer":{"method":"wrr"}}},"frontends":{"frontend-my-awesome-app-app-default":{"entryPoints":["https","http"],"backend":"backend-my-awesome-app-app-default","routes":{"service-default":{"rule":"Host:docker.vps.ahri.net"}},"passHostHeader":true,"priority":0,"basicAuth":[]}}}"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Last docker config received more than 2s, OK"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating frontend frontend-my-awesome-app-app-default"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Wiring frontend frontend-my-awesome-app-app-default to entryPoint https"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating route service-default Host:docker.vps.ahri.net"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating backend backend-my-awesome-app-app-default"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer wrr"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating server service at https://172.18.0.3:9000 with weight 0"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating retries max attempts 1"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Wiring frontend frontend-my-awesome-app-app-default to entryPoint http"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating route service-default Host:docker.vps.ahri.net"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating entryPoint redirect http -> https : ^(?:https?:\/\/)?([\w\._-]+)(?::\d+)?(.*)$ -> https://$1:443$2"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating backend backend-my-awesome-app-app-default"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer wrr"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating server service at https://172.18.0.3:9000 with weight 0"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating retries max attempts 1"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :443"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :80"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="LoadCertificateForDomains [docker.vps.ahri.net]..."
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Look for provided certificate to validate [docker.vps.ahri.net]..."
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="No provided certificate found for domains [docker.vps.ahri.net], get ACME certificate."
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:28Z" level=debug msg="Loading ACME certificates [docker.vps.ahri.net]..."
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:29Z" level=error msg="map[docker.vps.ahri.net:[docker.vps.ahri.net] acme: Could not determine solvers]"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:29Z" level=error msg="Error getting ACME certificates [docker.vps.ahri.net] : Cannot obtain certificates map[docker.vps.ahri.net:[docker.vps.ahri.net] acme: Could not determine solvers]+v"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:36:29Z" level=warning msg="A new release has been found: 1.5.3. Please consider updating."
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:38:12Z" level=debug msg="Look for provided certificate to validate [docker.vps.ahri.net]..."
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:38:12Z" level=debug msg="No provided certificate found for domains [docker.vps.ahri.net], get ACME certificate."
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:38:12Z" level=debug msg="Challenge GetCertificate docker.vps.ahri.net"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:38:12Z" level=debug msg="ACME got nothing docker.vps.ahri.net"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:38:15Z" level=debug msg="Look for provided certificate to validate [docker.vps.ahri.net]..."
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:38:15Z" level=debug msg="No provided certificate found for domains [docker.vps.ahri.net], get ACME certificate."
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:38:15Z" level=debug msg="Challenge GetCertificate docker.vps.ahri.net"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:38:15Z" level=debug msg="ACME got nothing docker.vps.ahri.net"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:38:15Z" level=warning msg="Error forwarding to https://172.18.0.3:9000, err: tls: oversized record received with length 20527"
traefik    | time="2018-02-28T07:38:15Z" level=warning msg="Error forwarding to https://172.18.0.3:9000, err: tls: oversized record received with length 20527"
```

I'm not sure how to go about debugging this as I'm not familiar with traefik or with letsencrypt and its ACME protocol. Can anyone spot my mistake(s)?

It's perhaps worth noting that due to the failure to get the certs via ACME, the cert being used is the Traefik default cert. The last two lines of the log are me trying to access `https://docker.vps.ahri.net` with Chrome.

Comment: I'm not sure about traefik, I guess this message `Error forwarding to https://172.18.0.3:9000, err: tls: oversized record received with length 20527` helps?

Comment: @harshavmb I'm not sure; that comes up when I try visiting the page with Chrome, i.e. https://docker.vps.ahri.net (it's not currently running though) - I've updated the question slightly to clarify this point.